# How to get element ID in UiApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create an app script for a Google Spreadsheet that I have. I created a script for another sheet a couple of years ago and I can't remember how to to get the component ID.

Here's the code:

```
var pointsSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1o8_f063j1jYZjFEnI_P7uAztpnEAvQ6mc3Z1_Owa69Y');
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.loadComponent("Marks")); //IT IS NOT CALLED MARKS!

  var panel = app.getElementById("VerticalPanel1");
  var text = app.createPasswordTextBox().setName("text");
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("getResults").addCallbackElement(text);

  panel.add(text);
  panel.add(app.createButton("Get Record", handler));

  //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app); 
  return app;
}
...
```

The commented part where it says "IT IS NOT CALLED MARKS" is the part I'm talking about. In my other script this works, but in the new script it doesn't work. How do I find the component name (if that's what it's called)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run a script that uses the GUI Builder, a couple of years ago it was possible but now it is not anymore (since october 2013)! See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset).

I saw that because you are using `app.loadComponent("Marks")`, which was the method to call the Ui components created in the GUI Builder.

The old apps built with it still work but you can't create/modify it.

**EDIT** following your comment :

You will have to build your UI from scratch using either UiApp - which uses the same elements as the GUI builder and the same syntax - or HTML Service.

The latter is much more powerfull but uses a completely different approach as it uses client JavaScript in combination with server code. Take a look at the docs and tutos and make your choice ;-)

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem and yes, I couldn't find that GUI builder option anymore. What's the solution though?

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. I used UiApp and everything's good.